# Faceting array of words in marklogic

Tags: facet, marklogic

I am new to marklogic and I started my exploration using Corona APi. I have stored some documents using store API. Now I want to perform faceting on an array of words. I have indexed a json document which looks like

...
"aothor":"name",
"published_date":"20-10-2011",
"nouns":["n1","n2"],
....
I am able to do faceting on author field after making it a range index field. I am not sure how I can get count of all words in this "nouns" field.

Please suggest how can I do faceting on this or any other way to get a frequency of these words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no native support for faceting on array objects. They are planning to include this in next Marklogic release.
The workaround solution is suggest here https://github.com/marklogic/Corona/issues/86

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how Corona stores JSON. But if each noun is stored in its own element, you could create another range index. Frequency data comes from range indexes.

If you have not already reviewed them, https://github.com/marklogic/Corona/wiki/Facet-Queries and https://github.com/marklogic/Corona/wiki/Range-Management might help.

Comment: Thanks.. I have already gone through these links... array field does not comes under range-index support. It has support for string, number, boolean, date.
Please suggest how can store array field do be considered for faceting

Comment: It looks to me like a design limitation of Corona, specifically the way lib/json.xqy converts arrays to XML. So I recommend filing an RFE at https://github.com/marklogic/Corona/issues

Answer (score 0):

For getting facets on author filed, you need to create first range index on author element through soup UI or Curl tool. If you try to create range index through MarkLogic admin screen in database,then you need to make some configuration in MarkLogic. Follow below steps :

1. create range index in database, exaple: for "author" element
2. Go to, Configure->Gropus->Deafult->Namespcaes->and click on ADD tab
3. Enter value in prefix field  : "corona-index-author"
4. Enter value in namespace uri : `http://xqdev.com/prop/xml/<index+type%3d"range"+name%3d"author"><structure>xmlelement</structure><element>author</element><type>string</type><collation/></index>`
5. Click OK.
6. Restart the MarkLogic server(if needed).

Now hit the Your specif Url to get facet on author for  like this:

`http://localhost or ip":"corona-port-no"/facet/author?StructuredQuery={"and":[{"element":"author","equals":"Shakespear"},{"element":"published_date","equals":"20-10-2011"}]}&outputFormat=xml`

Comment: Thanks.. But I have mentioned that I am able to do faceting on Author field. I am struggling to do faceting on  Noun field, where I have array of words.